# Get RTSP URL from Youtube

Tags: url, youtube, rtsp

I have a video URL like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAAAAAAAAA

How can I get a RTSP URL for this video?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: Seems like Youtube stopped supporting this method.**

Go to:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{video-id}

For example:
If we want to get the RTSP link for this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUDm2xatms4&list=PLA9nd26sR8HD62LClHOBU93tuDKnJsfKa&feature=player_detailpage#t=0

We'd use:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/rUDm2xatms4

This will download an XML file for you. In there search for 'rtsp' and you'll get the full link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Discontinued on May 2015 as part of YouTube's *we don't care* API upgrading policy.

Comment: Could anyone confirm this, please?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore since the youtube stopped supporting v2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Go to this link, and Replace "VIDEOID" with the actual ID of the video you want:

http://m.youtube.com/add_favorite?v=VIDEOID

then right click the image of the video, and copy the link.

For example, if the video is http://youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDEFGHIJK, you would request http://m.youtube.com/add_favorite?v=ABCDEFGHIJK

The link is affectively permanent, but it will vary depending upon whether or not you are logged in and what preferences you have set when you request the page.

Comment: how to do this programatically?!!

Comment: When I did this the video was tiny will this result in a full size video stream?

Comment: Exactly where in your post can I find the rtsp:// URL value? Maybe this answer belongs to another question?

Answer (score 3):

I made a javascript function that can give you the rtsp of any youtube video, you just have to  set the original youtube url as param. Maybe it is what you are looking for.

Here's the [github](https://github.com/vrunoa/youtube-url2rtsp) link. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can always follow this [simple](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA7Kkhv30WA) 45 second video tutorial. And it will show you how to get the RTSP from any youtube video also.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below format and replace **VIDEO_ID** with your VIDEO's ID.
To view the same in android(chrome) enable "*Request desktop site*".
For more details see this [article](http://www.technicalwisdom.in/2013/12/play-mobile-youtube-video-on-computer.html).

> m.youtube.com/watch?v=**VIDEO_ID**&app=m&itct=CIYBEKQwGAAiEwjYqrOwmabLAhWII74KHWhnDt8yCmctaGlnaC1yY2g%3D&hl=en&client=mv-google

Comment: I checked now it is working in Desktop Browsers(chrome v48, Firefox v42) in windows 7. But android mobiles Browser do not support this. check this [youtube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i4WlbuRXrvU&app=m&itct=CIYBEKQwGAAiEwjYqrOwmabLAhWII74KHWhnDt8yCmctaGlnaC1yY2g%3D&hl=en&client=mv-google&gl=IN)  if it opens correctly.

Comment: Uhm, very strange. I'm testing on Firefox v44 in Windows 7; your link works, but my link ( [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JAAcDX7f9TU&app=m) ) doesn't.

Comment: I also tried with the additional parameters (as also suggested in the updated article), but that link won't work. :(

Comment: i have edited the answer above, and now this method is working.

Comment: uhm, how did you generate that "itct" parameter? I can't find documentation about what that means; and if I try to use your link with my video_id, it's still not working. :(

Comment: actually get it from java mobile(nokia x2-01) browser(opera-mini), Give me your **video_id**  let me try. This is only happening in windows not android ok.

Comment: uhm, ok, I tried your link - it works on both Windows or Android, while my link (i.e. your link with my video_id) doesn't work on windows, and it works on Android but a "Video not available" banner appears over the video (which is not playable of course). And the "itct" parameter gets removed. I tested it on Android 6 with Chrome and Firefox. Very strange :(

Comment: Your link: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i4WlbuRXrvU&app=m&itct=CIYBEKQwGAAiEwjYqrOwmabLAhWII74KHWhnDt8yCmctaGlnaC1yY2g%3D&hl=en&client=mv-google

My link: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JAAcDX7f9TU&app=m&itct=CIYBEKQwGAAiEwjYqrOwmabLAhWII74KHWhnDt8yCmctaGlnaC1yY2g%3D&hl=en&client=mv-google

Comment: RTSP  is mainly used for mobile viewing, and  As far as i understood  YouTube video link you gave was some kind of restricted for mobile devices by the uploader. So even normally without any special parameters  it didn't played in android nor in java mobile. [Android browser- screenshots](https://1d20a408c54070c36e931dbc04256e8643d7a0ef.googledrive.com/host/0B2FIG77uEdgQRnkteGNxaHVpNms/Screenshot_2016-07-01-18-24-09.png).

Comment: @ocramot i found it strange that when i tried to play the video with vpn proxy with USA location it played well normally in mobiles, in fact with parameters also. So it is **country restricted** perhaps. _Screen shots_ of [Android browser](https://1d20a408c54070c36e931dbc04256e8643d7a0ef.googledrive.com/host/0B2FIG77uEdgQRnkteGNxaHVpNms/Screenshot_2016-07-01-20-42-26.png) and [mobile site from desktop](https://1d20a408c54070c36e931dbc04256e8643d7a0ef.googledrive.com/host/0B2FIG77uEdgQRnkteGNxaHVpNms/mobile%20rtsp.jpg)

Comment: yep, it must be that specific case. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience.
1) Browse the video.The url wud look like this
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHRpGg2_Yqs
2) After replacement of **www** with **m**
   http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oHRpGg2_Yqs
3) Right click on the image now loaded in the browser during step 2 (dat wud be the rtsp addr)

Answer (score 1):

I have an old BlackBerry Bold 9900, and when using the stock web browser on the YouTube website and play a video, it plays via rstp (in the browser), so I can just go and copy the url out of the url bar. That's probably kind of an inconvenient method of finding it, but it works. Maybe if you changed your user agent to that of an old BlackBerry (mine is on os 6.x.x)?

Hope this is useful,

jBit

EDIT: Just figured out how to do this.
1. Install user agent switcher chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-g/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake/related)
2. Open it and go to "options"
3. Click the big green "New User-Agent" button
4. Put "Blackberry" in the name field
5. Paste this into the user-agent field: `headers: 'User-Agent: BlackBerry9800/6.6.0.207 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1/UCWEB8.1.0.104/161/999'
    result: { browser: { name: 'UC Browser', version: '8.1', type: browser }, engine: { name: Gecko }, os: { name: 'BlackBerry OS', version: '6.6' }, device: { type: mobile, subtype: smart, manufacturer: RIM, model: 'BlackBerry Torch 9800' } }
    readable: 'UC Browser 8.1 on a RIM BlackBerry Torch 9800 running BlackBerry OS 6.6'`

6. Press save
7. Go to youtube; notice the much older ui
8. Search for a video of your choice and click on it
9. There will be a box with a video thumbnail underneath which there will be a "Watch video" hyperlink
10. Right-click it and press "copy link address"
11. You now have a streamable rtsp link
12. Profit!

Comment: didn't work for me, (http) link just takes you to a UI that lets you add the video to a playlist. Guess they changed that too