# Play MP3 files and youtube videos on a webpage on Blackberry, Android, iPhones

Tags: android, blackberry, youtube-api, html5-video, html5-audio

I am developing a mobile website with audio (links to self hosted MP3 files) and video (youtube links). My target users are the blackberry, android and iphone platforms.

I want the audio/video file to play within the browser using HTML5 with flash fallback, or else to open the device's native media player. If both fail, I can then show a link to download the MP3 or a link to visit the youtube page.

For the Youtube video, I [read something on S/O about RSTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937903/get-rtsp-url-from-youtube) but it's a manual process, I don't know if there is any way to automate this via the Youtube API.

From my findings, the blackberry might tend to be the most challenging platform because I cannot find a lot of audio/video javascript/css/html support for it. Unfortunately, it's the major target platform in my case.

Links to any articles, resources or plugins that can help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the video part. I stumbled on a blog with this info and unfortunately as I kept on trawling the web I have lost the link again. Here is what he/she suggested.

E.g. PHP code for a video with youtube ID Mgi4fkp9YAg this is what I did. It worked fine on blackberry and Android, I don't have an iPhone but I guess it should work there too:

```
    <?php
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $pos_blackberry = strrpos($ua, "blackberry");
    $pos_webkit = strrpos($ua, "webkit");

    if (!($pos_blackberry === false)) {
        if (!($pos_webkit === false)) {          
                    $output = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgi4fkp9YAg"><img width="310" height="160" title="videotitle" alt="videoalt" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Mgi4fkp9YAg/0.jpg" /></a>';        
            }
    }else{
        $output = '<iframe width="310" height="160" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Mgi4fkp9YAg?controls=1&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1"></iframe>';
    }

    echo $output;
?>
```

Now I need to know how to play self-hosted MP3 files within webpages on blackberry and android. Still looking...

Comment: I'm accepting my own findings on the video alone, because I have realized that there is no reliable way to play mp3 files on a blackberry webpage. And also on an Android 2.2 (Froyo) webpage.