# GET Access Token for Installed Applications for YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube, oauth-2.0

I want to get YouTube Videos in Android VideoView for my application.
I am going through the Google's YouTube API. I have generated the Client ID,Client Secret,redirect-URL and code by the help of this API Documentation.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow

Next step is to get Access Token for Installed Applications, I am doing the same as the above Doc is explaining but getting this error.

**java.io.FileNotFoundException:** https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=4/sfsekiMy-EWE_7der69fy3wsdfdsseclient_id=412600012302.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=0P7H4yqRZY2jmpluiyswqnbz&redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&grant_type=authorization_code

Any help is highly appreciated OR you can suggest some way to access YouTube video in my Android App using only MediaPlayer and VideoView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this thread [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

Steps:

a. Create a new Activity, for your player(fullscreen) screen with menu options. Run the mediaplayer and UI in different threads.

b. For playing media - In general to play audio/video there is mediaplayer api in android. FILE_PATH is the path of file - may be url(youtube) stream or local file path

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(FILE_PATH);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Soham: This work for rtsp (Real Time Streaming protocol) only as i already tested this ..... But the Youtube videos we view in Web doesn't contain rtsp urls, than how to get rtsp url for each and every video on runtime.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937903/get-rtsp-url-from-youtube