# I want to play rtsp with vlc dotnet using wpf. Following is the code i have written

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, libvlc

I want to create a wpf application for rtsp. I have tried vlclib and followed all the instruction, so dont get any issue but is does not play video.The following is the code for playing the youtube video

VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\";

```
        VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins\\";
```

private void buttonRtsp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myVlcControl.Stop();

```
        if (myVlcControl.Media != null)
        {
            myVlcControl.Media.ParsedChanged -= MediaOnParsedChanged;
        }

        textBlockOpen.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        myVlcControl.Media = new LocationMedia("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxrnoGyBw4E");

        myVlcControl.Media.ParsedChanged += MediaOnParsedChanged;
        myVlcControl.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Wrong method to get the rtsp YouTube video. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937903/get-rtsp-url-from-youtube

Comment: Don't use the local VLC install, use nuget as documented [here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Getting-started#with-nuget-). As for your problem, share more info, such as logs and errors.